# Google map api for textsearch is showing zero results

Tags: flutter, dictionary, backend, google-developers-console

Google map api for textsearch is not showing any results even for the valid place search. It was working perfectly fine for many months but same code does not work now. I checked apikey, it is also correct and also have not exceeded the limit.
[image: This is what it gives me] . No any results even for the textsearch like 'cafe around me'.
Why is it showing zero results suddenly when it was working perfectly fine before. Please help

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)